# Проверка interface на индексируемость

Tags: golang, интерфейс

Я хочу написать функцию вывода срезов разных типов в консоль.

Можно написать что-то такое:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func PrintArr(arr interface{}) {
    switch v := arr.(type) {
    case []int:
        for i := range v {
            fmt.Println(v[i])
        }
    case []string:
        for i := range v {
            fmt.Println(v[i])
        }
    // И так описывать все типы
    default:
        panic("arr is not array")
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"1", "2"}
    PrintArr(a)
}
```

Но, понятное дело, получается очень длинный код. Хочется обойтись как-то поэлегантнее.

Я попытался сделать еще вот так:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func PrintArr(arr []interface{}) {
    for i := range arr {
        fmt.Println(arr[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"1", "2"}
    PrintArr(a)
}
```

Но появлялась ошибка `.\main.go:26:11: cannot use a (variable of type []string) as type []interface{} in argument to PrintArr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `reflect`-ом: https://go.dev/play/p/F-qGyLcv6ME

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func printValue(v reflect.Value) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(v.Interface()))
}

func PrintArr(arr interface{}) {
    defer func() {
        if recover() != nil {
            fmt.Println("<nil>")
        }
    }()
    v := reflect.ValueOf(arr)
    if v.Type().Kind() == reflect.Pointer {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    switch v.Type().Kind() {
    case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice:
        break
    default:
        printValue(v)
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        elem := v.Index(i)
        printValue(elem)
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"str1", "str2"}
    PrintArr(a)
    b := []int{1, 2, 3}
    PrintArr(b)
    c := []float64{12.34, 56.78}
    PrintArr(c)
    d := []struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
    }{{"John Dow", 42}, {"Marty Sue", 99}}
    PrintArr(d)
    PrintArr(&d)
    PrintArr(1)
    PrintArr(nil)
}
```

Функции `Value.Len` и `Value.Index` паникуют, если вызваны не для массива или среза, поэтому необходимо сначала проверить тип объекта. Заодно я решил печатать значения типа *указатель на срез* тоже как срез.

`fmt.Sprint` умеет строить приличное строковое представление для любых значений.